# Pandas - CSV file , how to take Month date from list of int32 column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hey Guys im trying to create a new col , from a dates col which like : "1/20/21 , 5/30/21 .. 11/5/21" , so i have 2 options here: 1 char , or 2 char till get "/" char.

```
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str[0:1]
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Month'].astype('int32')
all_data.head()
```

This option is takes only 1-9 months .. without 10,11,12 .
i tried to make :

```
index = all_data['Order Date'].find('\') # return the index of "/"
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str[0:index]
```

But its also not working... got error of type value. how can i make it works ?

Answer (score 1):

I think here is simplier convert values to datetimes and then use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
all_data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date']).dt.month
```

Or split by `/` and get first value:

```
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str.split('/').str[0].astype(int)
```

Or get numeric before start of string and first `/` in [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str.extract('^(\d+)/').astype(int)
```